# Ignoring second instance of preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping, preg-replace

I'm doing a web scrape that generates random data.

The string from the random data format is `RestaurantJimmys Outdoor Grill`

I have a `preg_replace` to remove Restaurant and keep the title.

However, when the name is `RestaurantSmith Family Restaurant` it turns into `Smith Family`

What is the best solution to keep the second instance?

**Code:**

```
preg_replace('/Restaurant/', '', $restaurantName);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the first instance of *Restaurant* always concatenated with the next string **without spaces**?

Comment: @RaxWeber That is correct.

Comment: Is it when `Restaurant` occurs at the _beginning_ of the string that it should be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried two ways for this that works:

```
$str = "RestaurantSmith Family Restaurant";

echo preg_replace("/Restaurant(\w+)/", "$1", $str);
```

and:

```
echo preg_replace("/Restaurant\B/", "", $str);
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate it!

Comment: And what if the first Restaurant has a space after it? =P

Comment: @MarcelJacquesMachado Clearly the OP said it won't have any space after it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and see if this helps:

```
 <?php
 echo preg_replace('/Restaurant/u', '', "RestaurantSmith Family  Restaurant", 1);
 ?>
```

Actually,

- `u` for UTF-8 text.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting a `RestaurantSmith Family` output.

Comment: ohh, let me see

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do that:

```
$text = 'RestaurantSmith Family Restaurant';
$pattern = '/^Restaurant/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

`^` is used to indicate the beginning of the text. So just the first occurrence of Restaurant will be replaced.

Comment: What if Restaurant is not at the beginning of the string? Then it won't work.

Comment: Where is saying that?